# How to change UITextField keyboard type to email in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

In objective-c I can just say the following.

```
[self.promoTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
```

I tried googling it but just get ways to do it in objective-c.

Comment: I recently discovered that you can have the OS suggest an email address like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61170506/1898829

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Try this :

## Swift 3

```
self.promoTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.emailAddress
// Or Shorter version
self.promoTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

## Swift  < 3

```
self.promoTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress
```

Comment: You can also use the shorthand like this: `self.promoTextField.keyboardType = .EmailAddress`

Comment: If keyboardType of currently focussed textField needs to be changed without resigning it from the first responder, you must call reloadInputViews() after changing the keyboardType. Example: self.promoTextField.reloadInputViews()

Comment: Does anyone know why setting it the first time works, but for subsequent ones, you have to change `.keyboardType` to something else and then back again?

Answer (score 17):

[The documentation about `UITextInputTraits`,](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/keyboardType) a protocol adopted by `UITextField`, says it's still here:

```
optional var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType { get set }
```

And the list of all `keyboardType`s is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIKeyboardType) :

```
enum UIKeyboardType : Int {
    case Default
    case ASCIICapable
    case NumbersAndPunctuation
    case URL
    case NumberPad
    case PhonePad
    case NamePhonePad
    case EmailAddress
    case DecimalPad
    case Twitter
    case WebSearch
}
```

Comment: For more details visit here
https://betterprogramming.pub/12-shades-of-keyboard-types-in-ios-a413cf93bf4f

Answer (score 8):

In `Swift 3` you might use:

`youremailfieldname.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.emailAddress`

Note the `lowercase` in `emailAddress`

> Note: also that you can assign the keyboard type in the `TextField`
>   definition in the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: This answer adds nothing new to the answers that already exist.

Comment: The other answers don't include the storyboard option, so thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try it in Swift 3:

```
let emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let text = UITextField()
    text.keyboardType = .emailAddress

    return text
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but to get the best experience I have to also set a few other properties.

```swift
TextField("Email", text: $email)
    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
    .autocapitalization(UITextAutocapitalizationType.none)
    .disableAutocorrection(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just set the type of entry to TextField you want to change.
e.g.

```
self.yourlTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress //shows keyboard with e-mail characters

self.yourTextField.keyboardType = .phonePad ////shows phone pad only..just numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes give UITextField extension to add one method, you can use like that "textField.chooseKeyboardType(keyboardType:.pad)", perhaps this is not a good way, but useful.

```
public extension UITextField {

func chooseKeyboardType(_ keyboardType:UIKeyboardType) {
    switch keyboardType {
    case .emailAddress:
        self.keyboardType = .emailAddress
    case .twitter:
        self.keyboardType = .twitter
    case .numberPad:
        self.keyboardType = .numberPad
    case .numbersAndPunctuation:
        self.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation
    case .asciiCapable:
        self.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
    case .URL:
        self.keyboardType = .URL
    case .decimalPad:
        self.keyboardType = .decimalPad
    case .namePhonePad:
        self.keyboardType = .namePhonePad


    default:
        self.keyboardType = .default
    }
}
}
```