# Swift - How to limit the a few specific text field only allow to insert int?

Tags: swift, int, uitextfield

How to limit the few specific text field only allow to insert int?
not all text fields. only a few specific ones.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change UITextField keyboard type to email in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404373/how-to-change-uitextfield-keyboard-type-to-email-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var yourTextField: UITextField!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            yourTextField.delegate = self
        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            //For mobile numer validation
            if textField == yourTextField {
                //Add specific int numbers
                let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123 ")//Here change this characters based on your requirement
                let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
                return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
            }
            return true
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried setting your textField's keyboard type?

```
yourTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

Can also look into the delegate method

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
return true
}
```

You can from there add logic to return true or false if the textField's selection meets your requirements